# List of Naturally Isomorphic Real Vector Space Pairs

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, big-list, vector-space-isomorphism, natural-transformations

Let's consider the category of finite dimensional real vector spaces (VS) / inner product spaces (IPS).

Which of the following pairs of isomorphic vector spaces (given appropriate dim constraints), are *naturally* isomorphic as VS/IPS? Are the natural isomorphisms unique? In the case IPS, is there always a natural isomorphism that is also isometric?

| Domain | Co-Domain | nat. iso. as VS? | nat. iso. as IPS? | nat. iso. unqiue? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $V$ | $V$ | ✔ | ✔ | ? |
| $V$ | $V^*$ | ✘ | ✔? | ? |
| $V$ | $(V^*)^*$ | ✔ | ✔ | ? |
| $U⊕V$ | $V⊕U$ | ✔ | ✔ | ? |
| $U⊗V$ | $V⊗U$ | ✔ | ✔ | ? |
| $U⊕(V⊕W)$ | $(U⊕V)⊕W$ | ✔ | ✔ | ? |
| $U⊗(V⊕W)$ | $(U⊗V)⊗W$ | ✔ | ✔ | ? |
| $U⊗(V⊕W)$ | $(U⊗V)⊕(U⊗W)$ | ✔ | ✔ | ? |
| $(U,V)$ | $U^*⊗V$ | ✔ | ✔ | ? |
| $(U⊗V, W)$ | $(U, (V,W))$ | ✔ | ✔ | ? |
| $ℝ^m⊕ℝ^n$ | $ℝ^{m+n}$ | if $m+n≤1$? | if $m+n≤1$? | ? |
| $ℝ^m⊗ℝ^n$ | $ℝ^{m⋅n}$ | if $m⋅n∈\{0,1,m,n\}$? | if $m⋅n∈\{0,1,m,n\}$? | ? |
| $ℝ^m⊕ℝ^n$ | $ℝ^k⊕ℝ^l$ | if $\{k,l\}=\{m,n\}$? | if $\{k,l\}=\{m,n\}$? | ? |
| $ℝ^m⊗ℝ^n$ | $ℝ^k⊗ℝ^l$ | if $\{k,l\}=\{m,n\}$? | if $\{k,l\}=\{m,n\}$? | ? |
| $ℝ^m⊗ℝ^n$ | $ℝ^n⊕…⊕ℝ^n$ | if $m≤1$? | if $m≤1$? | ? |

Feel free to suggest other common isomorphic pairs / edit the list.

Comment: The commutativity isomorphisms are natural for sums and tensors.

Comment: @jgon makes sense

Comment: The associativity isomorphisms are also natural. The fact that direct sums are naturally commutative and associative is a general fact about products/coproducts in categories. For tensor products it's because you can show that both triple products represent the functor that takes a vector space $Z$ to trilinear maps $U\times V\times W\to Z$.

Comment: For some of the other ones like the $\operatorname{Hom}$ ones a method of proof is to produce a natural transformation from one to the other and then show that this happens to be an isomorphism for finite dimensional vector spaces. E.g. produce $U^*\otimes V\to \operatorname{Hom}(U,V)$ and then show that this is either injective or surjective and use dimension counting to show that it is in fact an isomorphism.

Comment: Also for the $\mathbb{R}^n$ questions you need to be more careful about what exactly it means for an isomorphism to be natural. There are versions of those statements for direct sums and tensor products that do give natural isomorphisms for all $m$ and $n$. One way to define what you mean by naturality here is to use the category of vector spaces/inner product spaces with a choice of basis/orthogonal basis/orthonormal basis.

Comment: I think you should make clear that you consider functors with one or more variables and look for natural isomorphisms between such functors. For example, a covariant and a contravariant functor of one variable cannot be naturally isomorphic ($V$ and $V^*$).

Comment: @PaulFrost Thank you for the comment. I am a novice with respect to category theory, but I was under the impression that the mapping $V→V^*，v↦[x↦⟨v∣x⟩]$ would constitute a natural isomorphism between finite dimensional IPS. After re-reading [the section on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_transformation#Example:_dual_of_a_finite-dimensional_vector_space), it seems that this is true, only if we restrict the category to only include vector space homomorphisms that respect the inner product - i.e. isometries?